# Exception while deploying hibernate 4.3.5 ejb project in JBOSS5

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I want to deploy my ejb project into jboss 5.0.0 GA which uses hibernate 4.3.5 database connectivity but it throws me exception

> **15:57:05,129 ERROR [LogInterceptor] Unexpected Error in method: public abstract java.util.ArrayList
>   tr.Tr.loadText(java.lang.StringBuffer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
>   throws java.rmi.RemoteException java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.(HibernateSessionFactory.java:56)
>   at org.QueryFactory.updateBatch(QueryFactory.java:881)**

These jars does not conflict when i deploy in my web project which also uses hibenate 4.3.5 jars a don't no what to do

Comment: For the love of god, try to format your question a little, and separate the question from the error stack. This is unreadable!

Comment: From the error trace, my guess tells me that hibernate expects some  updated version of a library, which jboss5 is not providing